# Creating a custom product page layout template for a single product

Tags: magento-1.7, template

My goal is to create a new product page layout to be used for specific products.  The products will always be a Grouped item (but not all grouped items) and I want to be able to select the template on the product's "Design" tab.

I have followed numerous tutorials on creating new templates and have done the following:

I have a template module that I added the following to `config.xml`

```
<Rig_Template translate="label">
    <label>Rig Template</label>
    <template>page/1column-rigs.phtml</template>
    <layout_handle>cff_rig</layout_handle>
</Rig_Template>
```

I have duplicated `1column.phtml` and `view.php` to `1column-rigs.phtml` and `view-rigs.php`

At this point, the new template shows up in the dropdown list on the design tab.

This is where I'm not sure what I'm doing. In `local.xml` I have put the following:

```
<layout>
    <cff_rig translate="label">
        <label>Rig Template</label>
        <reference name="root">
           <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column-rigs.phtml</template></action>
           <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
        </reference>
           
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view-rigs.phtml">
               
                <!-- clipped -->
                     
           </block>
        </reference>
    </cff_rig>
</layout>
```

This code was mostly copied from the `<catalog_product_view>` section of `page.xml`.

The issue is that while this does show my modified `view-rigs.php`, it uses that template for all the products not just the one I set to Rig Template in the Design tab.  I feel like the code in the local is completely wrong.

I tried changing `<reference name="content">` to `<reference name="rigcontent">` and calling `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('rigcontent') ?>` in `1column-rigs.php`, but that breaks it and the main content of the page is blank.

What am I missing?
Thanks!

Comment: magento provided Custom Layout Update per product in admin side. please use this functionality in admin side : Catalog ->Manage Products edit any one product and see left side tab Design

Comment: Yes, I know that. You didn't read the whole question. This question is about CREATING the template. Edited to be clearer.